# Laurent Expansion $\frac{e^z}{z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Expand $\frac{e^z}{z-1}$ at $|z-1|>1$

$t=z-1\iff t+1=z$

$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(t+1)^n}{n!}$

$\frac{1}{t}=\frac{1}{1-1+t}$

Is it the way?

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{z-1}$ is already on the desired form, i.e. the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{z-1}$ about $z=1$ is just $\frac{1}{z-1}$.

Comment: @Winther So I just need to multiply it by the Laurent series of $e^{z-1}$?

Comment: Yes that's all you need to do here.

Comment: @Winther shouldn't it be of the form $\sum a_n(z-1)^n$? why is it enough, thanks you so much

Comment: Yes it should and that's exactly what you will find: $e^{z-1}/(z-1) = [1 + (z-1) + (z-1)^2/2+\ldots] / (z-1) = (z-1)^{-1} + 1\cdot (z-1)^0 + (z-1)^1/2 + \ldots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simpler**:

Don't forget the radius of convergence of the exponential function if infinite), so you can write

$${\rm e}^z={\rm e\,  e}^{z-1}={\rm e}\Bigl(1+(z-1)+\frac{(z-1)^2}{2}+\dots+\frac{(z-1)^n}{n!}+\dotsm\Bigr).$$

Comment: what I can I do with $\frac{1}{z-1}$ to add $z-1+1-1$?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to add. You only have to divide the above expansion by $z-1$.  The Laurent expansion here starts at degree $-1$.